# how to get url response(content : xml data) from solr search engine in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr

my url is :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select/?q=searchtext&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

How can i get response (xml data) from this url in asp.net. my result search is :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
String a = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

But, I cant get content of xml data.

Comment: ResponseUri is just the URL for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

String a = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

ResponseUri is just the URL for the response.  You need to use GetResponseStream().

You should probably be using the XmlDocument class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Your code would look something like this:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
        string root = doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```